# Why do we need -rdynamic option in gcc?

Tags: gcc, shared-libraries, symbols, elf, dynamic-linking

By default all symbols are exported to dynamic table, so why would we use `-rdynamic` flag? Even if we hide some symbols via attributes/`-fvisibility=hidden` - `-rdynamic` doesn't change result, it doesn't unhide previously hidden symbols. So what's the point in it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Symbols are only exported by default from shared libraries. `-rdynamic` tells linker to do the same for executables. Normally that's a bad idea but sometimes you want to provide APIs for dynamically loaded plugins and then this comes handy (even though one much better off using explicit [visibility annotations](http://anadoxin.org/blog/control-over-symbol-exports-in-gcc.html), [version script](http://anadoxin.org/blog/control-over-symbol-exports-in-gcc.html) or [dynamic export file](https://www.cs.kent.ac.uk/people/staff/srk21/blog/2011/12/01/)).

Comment: I was confused by output of nm utility, it somehow doesn't change type of symbol (T/t for exported/hidden symbols). readelf --dyn-syms works better, and shows effect of -rdynamic.

Comment: @IbraimGaniev Yes, I personally try to avoid `nm` because it's often imprecise.

Comment: What is an explicit export file?

Comment: @rostamn739 I've added a link