# List "never linked against" source file in C project

Tags: c, linux, compilation, linker, static-analysis

I would like to know if someone is aware of a trick to retrieve the list of files that had been (or ideally will be) used by linker to produce an executable.

Some kind of solution must exist. A a static source analyzer, or a hack, such as compiling with some weird flags, and analyzing produced executable with another tool, or force the linker to output this information.

The goal is to provide a tool that strip useless source files from a list of source files.

The end goal is to ease the build process, by allowing him to give a list of usable source files. Then my tool would only compile the ones actually used by linker instead of everything.

This would allow for some unit_test to still be runnable even if some others are broken and can't compile, while not asking the user to manually list every test dependencies manually in the cmake.

I am targetting linux for now, but will be intersted in the futur to do the same trick on others OS. So I would like a cross-platform solution, eventhought I doubt I will have it :)

Thanks for your help

Edit because I see that it is confusing, what I mean by

> allowing him to give a list of usable source file

is that, in cmake, for exemple. If you use `add_executable(name, sources)`, then **sources** is considered as the sources to compile and link on.

I want to wrap `add_executable`, so `sources` is viewed as a set of **usable if necessary** sources files.

Comment: This is going to be very tool-specific. FWIW, the `c` compilers that I've used only included source files that were explicitly mention for inclusion, but I guess that's not the case for you?

Comment: Hi @500-InternalServerError. I use cmake. And internally, I thinks cmake does what you say (explicitly list everything to compiler). And thats my probleme. I want to wrap cmake add_executable method. The wrapper would primarly filter useless stuff from the list, and pass that to add_executable instead of the raw list. The purpose is to use source discovery without the associated drawbacks. To avoid manually listing every test dependency. Maybe I misunderstood what you just said.

Comment: A debug compile and link should have enough information for you.

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid the idea of detecting *never linked source files* is not a fruitful one.

To build a program, CMake will not compile a source file if it not going to link the resulting object
file into the program. I can understand how you might think that this happens, but it doesn't happen.

CMake already does what you would like it to do and the same is true of every other build automation system going back to
their invention in the 1970s. The fundamental purpose of all
such systems is to ensure that the building of a program
compiles a source file `name.(c|cc|f|m|...)` *if and only if*
the object file `name.o` is going to be linked into the program
*and* is out of date or does not exist. You *can* always defeat this purpose by
egregiously bad coding of the project's build spec (CMakeLists.txt, Makefile, SConstruct, etc.),
but with CMake you would need to be really trying to do it, and
trying quite expertly.

If you do not want `name.c` to be compiled and the object file `name.o`
linked into a target program, then you do not tell the build system
that `name.o` or `name.c` is a prerequisite of the program. Don't tell
it what you know is not true. It is elementary competence not to specify redundant prerequisites of
a build system target.

The linker will link all its input object files into an output
program without question. It does not ask whether or not they are "needed"
by the program because it cannot answer that question. Neither the
linker nor any possible static analysis tool can know what program
you *intend* to produce when you input some object files for linkage.
It can only be assumed that you intend to produce the program that
results from the linkage of those object files, assuming the
linkage is successful.

If those object files cannot be linked into a program at all, the linker will tell you
that, and why. Otherwise, if you have linked object files that you didn't
intend to link, you can only discover that for yourself, by noticing
the mistake in the build log, or failing that by testing the program and/or inspecting its contents and comparing
your observations with your expectations.

Given your choice of object files for linkage, you can instruct the linker
to detect any code sections or data sections it extracts those object files in
which no symbols are defined that can be referenced by the program, and to
throw away all such unreferenced input sections instead of linking them
into the program. This is called linktime "garbage collection". You tell the
linker to do it by passing the option `-Wl,-gc-sections` in the
`gcc` linkage command. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6687630/1362568)
to learn how to maximise the collectible garbage. This is what you
can do to remove redundant object code from the linkage.

But you can only collect any garbage from a program in this way if the program
is *dynamically opaque*, i.e *not* linked with the option [`-rdynamic`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36692315/1362568)
: then the global symbols defined in the program's static image are not visible
to the OS loader and cannot be referenced from outside its static image by dynamic
libraries in the same process. In this case the linker can determine by static
analysis that a symbol whose definition is not referenced in the program's static
image cannot be referenced at all, since it cannot be referenced dynamically,
and if all symbols defined in an input section are statically unreferenced then
it can garbage-collect the section.

If the program has been linked `-rdynamic` then `-Wl,-gc-sections` will
collect no garbage, and this is quite right, because if the program is
not dynamically opaque then it is impossible for static analysis to determine that anything
defined in its linkage cannot be referenced.

It's noteworthy that although `-rdynamic` is not a default linkage
option for GCC, it *is* a default linkage option for CMake projects using
the GCC toolchain. So to use linktime garbage collection in CMake projects
you would always have to override the `-rdynamic` default. And obviously it would only be
valid to do this if you have determined that *it is alright* for the program to
be dynamically opaque.

Comment: Hey @Mike, thanks you for pointing me to thoses links (and you made me realize its  would be good to  remove the rdynamic option. But on the other parts, such as :"To build a program, CMake will not compile a source file if it not going to link the resulting object file into the program. I can understand how you might think that this happens, but it doesn't happen.". It's not what I am experiencing. And on the "Don't tell it what you know is not true" part, well that mean stop doing automatic source discovery, which mean modifying a gigantic list of source file in the cmake list. The purpose

Comment: of my question is to allow me, for futur projects, to do automatic source discovery. Which allow  to put every source in one folder and subfolders, and stop caring about them.  Without the actual drawback of what I said: useless compilation of everything for small unit-test executables. I want o be able to compile a litle unit-test executable without compiling every sources.

Comment: I thing by playing with the option --print-gc-sections that I discovered thanks of you, I may end up to be able to do what I want at least with GCC