# Can function loaded from dlopen call a function from the executable that loaded it?

Tags: c++, c, dlopen

### Setup

Suppose I wrote a program in C/C++ and wanted to allow plugin loading. The typical solution would be to write the plugin as:

**plugin.c**

```
int my_plugin_fn() {
    return 7;
}
```

And compile it using something like `gcc -fpic -shared -o plugin.so plugin.c`

Then, in the main program that loads this plugin, we might have:

**loader.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>

int main() {
    void *plugin_handle = dlopen("./plugin.so", RTLD_LAZY);
    if (!plugin_handle) {
        printf("Could not open shared object: %s\n", dlerror());
        return -1;
    }

    int (*fn)() = dlsym(plugin_handle, "my_plugin_fn");
    char *err = dlerror();
    if (err) {
        printf("Could not resolve symbol: %s\n", err);
        return -1;
    }

    printf("Plugin object returned: %d\n", fn());

    return 0;
}
```

I compiled loader.c with `gcc -o loader loader.c -ldl`, and after running it, the output was `Plugin object returned: 7`, as expected.

### Question

Suppose we want to add functions in our main program (loader.c) that plugins can use. For example,

**loader_v2.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>

int times_2(int x) {
    return 2*x;
}

int main() {
    void *plugin_handle = dlopen("./plugin_v2.so", RTLD_LAZY);
    if (!plugin_handle) {
        printf("Could not open shared object: %s\n", dlerror());
        return -1;
    }

    int (*fn)() = dlsym(plugin_handle, "my_plugin_fn");
    char *err = dlerror();
    if (err) {
        printf("Could not resolve symbol: %s\n", err);
        return -1;
    }

    printf("Plugin object returned: %d\n", fn());

    return 0;
}
```

**plugin_v2.c**

```
extern int times_2(int);

int my_plugin_fn() {
    return times_2(7);
}
```

Compiling and running these files in the same way as before produces `Could not open shared object: ./loader_v2: symbol lookup error: ./plugin_v2.so: undefined symbol: times_2`.

Is there a way to have plugins loaded using `dlopen()` call functions from the program that loaded them?

Comment: That would be gcc-option `-rdynamic` when linking the main executable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there a way to have plugins loaded using dlopen() call functions from the program that loaded them?

Yes, but the function that you want to call from the main executable must be *exported* from it, which does *not* happen by default. You can see which symbols are exported from your main binary with `nm -D loader`.

You can export *all* functions defined in the main executable by linking it with the `-rdynamic` flag.

Some linkers, most notably newer versions of GNU-ld, GOLD and LLD, support the `--export-dynamic-symbol` flag, which allows one to *selectively* export just the symbol(s) you need.

In your case, you would link your `loader` executable with `-Wl,--export-dynamic-symbol=times_2`.

Comment: This is better than callbacks. See ["What exactly does `-rdynamic` do and when exactly is it needed?"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36700270/9305398).

Comment: Confirmed that this works! My version of ld (2.34.0) doesn't have the `--export-dynamic-symbol` option, but you can use `--dynamic-list` and write file that lists the symbols you want to export. For me, this file looked like `{times_2;};`

Answer (score 2):

The best way to do something like this is with a function pointer.  You would pass the function pointer into the library function, which would subsequently call it.

So the library function would look like this:

```
int my_plugin_fn(int (*cb)(int)) {
    return cb(7);
}
```

The call to `dlsym` would then look like this:

```
int (*fn)(int (*)(int)) = dlsym(plugin_handle, "my_plugin_fn");
```

And you would call the library function like this:

```
printf("Plugin object returned: %d\n", fn(times_2));
```

Comment: This does what I need. Out of curiosity, is this the only way? For example, is it possible to get the link editor to resolve the symbol when using dlopen on plugin_v2.so?

Comment: @MarcoMerlini Not when using `dlopen` as the main executable is not linked to the library.  Had the library been listed as a dynamic library at link time and `my_plugin_fn` called directly by name then you could do it.

Comment: You could put the common function in a separate shared library that both the executable and the dlopen library link with.

Comment: This answer is not entirely wrong, but isn't necessarily "the best way".

Comment: I've accepted @EmployedRussian's answer, but I sill think this is a great answer because it's portable. This works on both Windows and Linux