# Clang uses a linked shared lib to decide which symbols to export?

Tags: c, gcc, linker, clang, elf

Take this toy code for an executable and a shared library:

```c
// main.c
void foo() {}
int main() { return 0; }

// bar.c
void foo();
void bar() { foo(); }
```

Let's build without optimizations, first with gcc:

```
$ gcc -fpic -shared -o libbar_gcc.so bar.c
$ gcc -L. -lbar_gcc -o prog_gcc main.c
```

and observe that `foo` doesn't appear in the `.dynsyms` section - i.e., isn't exported from the executable:

```
$ readelf --dyn-syms prog_gcc | grep foo
$
```

Now try the same with clang, and see that it *does* export `foo`:

```
$ clang -fpic -shared -o libbar_clang.so bar.c
$ clang -L. -lbar_clang -o prog_clang main.c
$ readelf --dyn-syms prog_clang | grep foo
    6: 0000000000001130     6 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   13 foo
```

If we don't link against `libbar_clang`, `foo` *isn't* exported:

```
$ clang -fpic -shared -o libbar_clang.so bar.c
$ clang -o prog_clang main.c
$ readelf --dyn-syms prog_clang | grep foo
$
```

Even more surprising, if we restore the link against libbar but change `bar`'s source to *not* call `foo`:

```c
// bar.c
void bar() { }
```

We'd see that again `foo` isn't exported!

```
$ clang -fpic -shared -o libbar_clang.so bar.c
$ clang -L. -lbar_clang -o prog_clang main.c
$ readelf --dyn-syms prog_clang | grep foo
$
```

So modifying the source in a dependent shared library - *without* changing the source or the linkage of the executable - changes clang's decision on what to export from the executable. What kind of sorcery is this??

I'm on Ubuntu 20, clang 14.0.6 and gcc 9.4.0.  Both use the `ld` linker.

Comment: What happens if you modify `foo()` to call `printf()` and emit some output, and then call `bar()` from within `main()`?  As currently posted, you never call `bar()` and `foo()` literally doesn't do anything.  Thus they'd both be subject to being elided under [the as-if rule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15718262/what-exactly-is-the-as-if-rule) because neither `foo()` nor `bar()` result in any observable behavior.

Comment: @AndrewHenle That's pretty much the program I started from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36700270/89706 .  Clang's weird behavior persists there.

Comment: @AndrewHenle my comment was incomplete: turns out that if I call `bar()` from `main()`, gcc starts to export `foo` just like clang.  I'm writing an answer now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the breakthrough came while diffing verbose command lines of clang & gcc: turns out that on my distro, by default gcc uses `--as-needed` and clang uses `--no-as-needed`. I.e., the gcc driver guides the linker to only link against shared libraries which actually define needed symbols (that are yet undefined), while the clang driver guides the linker to merrily link against any shared libs which appear on the command line.

But how does that cause the observable difference in the question?

My current understanding is that while linking the executable, the default linker logic exports only symbols which the linker *can see are actually needed* to satisfy linkage elsewhere. If the linker can see that some dependent library relies on the executable to implement some symbol, that symbol would be exported without further user intervention.

Sometimes the linker cannot see that a symbol is needed by a library - say if it is loaded at runtime by `dlopen` and isn't visible to the linker in the first place. In such a case the user must intervene, probably with adding `-rdynamic` to the link line - thereby forcing all public symbols to be exported from the executable.

Anyway, in the original case in question:

1. `libbar.so` is not used directly from the executable (until we
   add a `bar()` call from `main()`!), and so -
2. it is dropped from linkage by gcc which defaults to `--as-needed`, and
3. The linker cannot see that `libbar.so` needs the symbol `foo` and does not export it.

---

I'm dumping this here in case this is of interest to anyone, and also  please note this is largely a hypothesis. I'm still curious whether anyone can confirm or refute this.

Comment: "turns out by default gcc uses --as-needed" -- this isn't true _in general_, but that is how Debian configures GCC. You would get a different result on Fedora.

Comment: @EmployedRussian thank you, adding "on my distro" to the answer